# Android BTC clients that remotely use my Bitcoin Core wallet?

Tags: wallet, android

Are there any Android BTC clients that remotely use my Bitcoin Core wallet so I don't have to use another wallet specific for my phone? I am running my own BTC node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Something like that would be problematic security wise because it means you have to open up your computer running Bitcoin Core to the rest of the internet. Having two seperate wallets is not really much of an inconvenience because it is easy to send bitcoins between them.

Comment: The Bitcoin Core's JSON-RPC server supports SSL, so it could be possible securely.